# How to get complex data from [FromBody] attribute in WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

When I try send request "http://localhost:1234/api/case/create?signature=123456"
from Postman (Google Extension) using "form-data" in body request, I get error:

"Message": "The request entity's media type 'multipart/form-data' is not supported for this resource.",
"ExceptionMessage": "No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'Case' from content with media type 'multipart/form-data'.", 
"ExceptionType": "System.Net.Http.UnsupportedMediaTypeException".

My action:

```
    [Route("create")]
    public object Create([FromBody]Case newCase, string signature)
    {
        var member = _memberService.GetUserByToken(signature);
        if (member != null)
        {
            var caseId = _caseService.Add(newCase, member);

            return Ok(new { caseId });
        }

        return NotFound();
    }
```

Comment: Show your request content-type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add header **Content-Type: application/json** in Postman

[image]

Comment: I added header "Content-Type: application/json" in Postman, but then I get newCase = null.

Comment: Try to use Raw data for POST. Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19037636/web-api-2-post-request-simulation-in-postman-rest-client

Comment: Yes, it works with Raw data and Content-Type: application/json, thank you. But what's difference between form-data and raw? I'm going to write console app to test my api.

Comment: Here https://www.getpostman.com/docs/requests you can find description about requests in postman. In a short: your web api action expects raw json data which then will be serialized to object. When you use form-data in postman the request is just like dictionary (key => value).