# How to test a web api post method which receives a class

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, postman

I have created an ASP.NET web API which has a controller named `ImageSaveController`. This has an `InsertImage` method which inserts data into database and is an `HttpPost` method. This method receives an object of type `ImageData` as a parameter. The code for the controller and the parameter class are given below:

```
public class ImageSaveController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult InsertImage(ImageData imageData)
    {
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection conn = null;
        try
        {               
            //Image save to database code here
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Content(HttpStatusCode.NotModified, ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (conn != null)
                conn.Close();
        }
        return Content(HttpStatusCode.OK,""); 
    }
}

//ImageData class
public class ImageData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public byte[] ImageValue { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to test it from a client. As you can notice, the `ImageValue` property of the `ImageData` class is a `byte` array. Not sure how to pass the C# class parameter to this method. Ideally I would like to pass the parameter as `json` and I am not sure how to construct the `json` for this purpose. I am also not sure whether it could be tested using the chrome app called postman.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open postman enter your url to the action: 
Add header: Content-Type - application/json. 
In body tab check "raw" (JSON) and type your data.

```
POST /api/ImageSave/InsertImage/ HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:32378
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

```
{
    "id" : 1,
    "imageValue" : [11,141,123,121]
}
```

source [Web API 2 POST request simulation in POSTMAN Rest Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19037636/web-api-2-post-request-simulation-in-postman-rest-client)

If you want to make good tests, the better solution is to write unit tests.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I use to do:
Use a REST client tester like Postman or Fiddler. I use Postman which is an app for Google Chrome.

For easy construction of JSON you can create a HttpGet method on you controller and return a fake constructed `ImageData` and call it from Postman. Here you will see the JSON and use that for input to the POST method.

```
public class ImageSaveController : ApiController
{
    public ImageData Get()
    {
         return new ImageData
         {
             // insert test data here
         };
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult InsertImage(ImageData imageData)
    {
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection conn = null;
        try
        {               
            //Image save to database code here
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Content(HttpStatusCode.NotModified, ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (conn != null)
                conn.Close();
        }
        return Content(HttpStatusCode.OK,""); 
    }
}
```