# Web API Post Method not working

Tags: api, asp.net-web-api

I have a webapi controller and following is a post method.

```
   public HttpResponseMessage Register(string email, string password)
   {

   }
```

How do I test from the browser?

When I test it from the browser with the following , it is not hitting the controller.

```
http://localhost:50435/api/SignUp/?email=sini@gmail.com&password=sini@1234
```

It is giving me the below error.

> Can't bind multiple parameters ('id' and 'password') to the request's
>   content.

Can you please help me???

Comment: Does that even compile? You have one "[" in your parameter list...

Comment: To test action in WebApi I recommend you use [TestClient](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/yaohuang1/2012/12/02/adding-a-simple-test-client-to-asp-net-web-api-help-page/) or request composer in [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38418787/how-to-test-a-web-api-post-method-which-receives-a-class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get an error, because you cannot pass multiple parameter to WebApi in this way.

First option:
You can create a class and pass data through from body in this way:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string email {get;set;}
    public string password {get;set;}
}

public HttpResponseMessage Register([FromBody] Foo foo) 
{
    //do something
    return Ok();
}
```

Second Option:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Register([FromBody]dynamic value)
{
    string email= value.email.ToString();
    string password = value.password.ToString();
}
```

And pass json data in this way:

```
{
  "email":"abc@test.com",
  "password":"123@123"
}
```

**Update:**

If you wan to get data from URL, then you can use Attribute Routing.

```
[Route("api/{controller}/{email}/{password}")]
public HttpResponseMessage Register(string email, string password) 
{
    //do something
    return Ok();
}
```

Note:
URL should be :  `http://localhost:50435/api/SignUp/sini@gmail.com/sini@1234`
*Don't forget to enable attribute routing in `WebApiConfig`

If you use this way, you will have security issue.*

Comment: I went for the "First option:".

Comment: How do I call this from the browser?

Comment: Is this way : http://localhost:50435/api/SignUp/?email=sini@gmail.com&password=sini@1234

Comment: You can use extension of browser [RestClient](http://restclient.net/) if you are using Firefox or  [Advanced REST client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo) for Chrome

Comment: I've added answer for get data from body, and you are trying to get data from URL