# Http post method seen as http get method

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have this javascript snippet :

```
$.ajax({
                type: "Post",
                contentType: 'application/json',
                url: "../api/Pointage/GetPointages",
                 data: JSON.stringify({
                    laDate: DateConsultation,
                    lstcols: Collaborators,
                    lEquipe: equipe,
                    Type: 3,
                }),
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    call3(data);
                }
            });
```

the signature of the service method is the following :

```
[HttpPost]
public List<ItemStatistiquesPointageMonth> GetPointages(Nullable<System.DateTime> laDate = null, List<Collaborateur> lstcols =null, Nullable<int> lEquipe = null, int Type = -1)
```

When I make the call, the serive is unreachable !!

So what is the reason of this problem ? How can I fix it?

Comment: try `method` instead of `type` - though I thought jquery supports both (depends on jquery version maybe)

Comment: Here, as we seen in the ajax call, you're passing data trough body, but in method have to not declare any `[FromBody]` and even how you can pass multiple parameter in this way?

Comment: As @Div pointed out, try creating a model with those properties and having that as the action argument instead.

Comment: You can refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40147761/4753489) for reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a model class which reflect the object you create in the client

```
public class dataModel
{
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> laDate { get; set; }
    public List<Collaborateur> lstcols { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> lEquipe { get; set; } 
    public int Type { get; set; } 
}
```

And then add it to the method with the FromBody attribute

```
[HttpPost]
public List<ItemStatistiquesPointageMonth> GetPointages([FromBody] dataModel data){}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a Model with your paramaters and pass it to your post method

```
[HttpPost]
public List<ItemStatistiquesPointageMonth> GetPointages([FromBody] MyModel model)
```

also use `dataType: "json"`